# Photo recovery but for a renamed photo with .BAK extension

Tags: data-recovery

Seems like most extension based file recovery apps on playstore only supports for rooted phone. Most photo recovery works fine but the file I deleted was renamed with a `.bak` extension. So I wonder if there is a way to recover extension based files even if the device not rooted?

Or would the photo recovery apps detect the `.bak` file extension as image and still recover it as photo?

Comment: Technically, the type of file is not determined by the extension, but by [its file signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures). E.g. a JPEG image file is still a JPEG image file even if it has `jpg`, `bak`, `xyz` or even no extension. So, it will depend on whether the recovery app only uses file extension or also check its file signature to determine if a file is considered as an image file or not.

Comment: Any app you can think of that determines file signature?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any.

Comment: While this site is not about (explicit) software recommendations, let's see (and rephrase) your question as asking for a how-to. So, for starters, have you seen our [data-recovery tag-wiki](/tags/data-recovery/info) already? // PS: some file recovery apps you can find [in my app listing here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_datawipe#group_872). I've not tried any of those myself, so I cannot give further details on them.